Why is my Snow-Video-Overlay not transparent?
I downloaded the following snow video effect: https://www.fxelements.com/products/clips/snow-003
Then i put it into the following html page:
<style>
  /* Hintergrundbild für die Seite */
  body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url('https://your-background-image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  /* Video-Overlay */
  .snow-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none; /* Interaktionen deaktivieren */
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Schnee Overlay Video -->
<video class="snow-overlay" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="Snow_Original.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="path-to-your-snow-overlay-video.mov" type="video/quicktime">
  Ihr Browser unterstützt kein HTML5 Video.
</video>

</body>
</html>

Unfortunately it is not transparent and i wonder, if it is because of the video (video codec) or because of the html or css?
I already tried to convert different mp4 video snow effects to webm but had no luck at all.

There's quite a lot of information about this on the internet. I'm not sure what you've tried, but it seems to be tricky to do. Perhaps this blog posting will help?

Thinking about it, using a video for a snow effect might not be very efficient. Why not use a bit of CSS, for example: https://codepen.io/alphardex/pen/dyPorwJ CSS is very adaptable. You can find hundreds of other examples out there.

Thanks, you're right - seems to be tricky - i just tried your way and it works pretty good! Thank you very much! Still wondering, how to do it with videos...
